# how to access php variable out side of a foreach loop

Tags: php

i have a veriable named (num) which is used for increments changes names of ids by 1 num+1 but in my foreachloop i cant access it .

i tried declaring it before the loop still doesnot work

```
<?php $num = 0; ?>
<?php foreach($listings as $list):?>
    <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" value="<?php echo $list['title'];?>" id="visit<?php echo $num+1;?>" name="treatment<?php echo $num+1;?>">
            <label for="visit<?php echo $num+1;?>" class="css-label"><?php echo $list['title']?> <strong><?php echo $list['price'];?><span>&#163;</span></strong></label>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach;   ?>
</ul>
<hr>
<input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $num;?>" name="total"/>
```

i want the input ids to be incremented by 1 like `treatment1`,`treatment2`

Comment: Can't replicate the problem... https://3v4l.org/40k5h

Comment: use `... as $num => $list` and skip the outside declaration of `$num`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should increment the `$num` variable by doing `$num++;` once inside the loop, then print it where you need it with `<?php echo $num; ?>` without using `<?php echo $num+1; ?>` - as doing so will only increment it as you echo it - not add one to each iteration.

```php
<?php 
$num = 0;
foreach($listings as $list):
    $num++; // Increment $num for each iteration
    ?>
    <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" value="<?php echo $list['title'];?>" id="visit<?php echo $num;?>" name="treatment<?php echo $num;?>">
            <label for="visit<?php echo $num;?>" class="css-label"><?php echo $list['title']?> <strong><?php echo $list['price'];?><span>&#163;</span></strong></label>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

If your `$listings` is numeric indexed, you can use the key of each element in the array instead by doing

```php
foreach($listings as $num=>$list):
    ?>
    <li>
        <div class="checkbox">
            <input type="checkbox" class="css-checkbox" value="<?php echo $list['title'];?>" id="visit<?php echo $num;?>" name="treatment<?php echo $num;?>">
            <label for="visit<?php echo $num;?>" class="css-label"><?php echo $list['title']?> <strong><?php echo $list['price'];?><span>&#163;</span></strong></label>
        </div>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you did not set the value of $num variable you just only print or echo it inside the html tags. You need to add or increment the $num variable  inside the loop like this.

```
 <?php $num++; ?>
```

or

```
 <?php $num = $num+1; ?>
```